# How can I find A matrix who has A^3=?

Tags: matrices, inverse, matrix-equations

My question is to find a matrix $A∈\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ for which
$${A}^{3} =\begin{bmatrix} 64 & 64 \\ -9 & 16\end{bmatrix}^{-1}.$$
I tried to write this matrix like A^3=A^2*A after taking inverse but couldnt find A. How  can I solve this problem in a shortest way?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you know about Jordan Normal Form?

Comment: J=P^-1*A*P but then:S

Comment: Hint: if $J$ is a Jordan block, what is $J^3$? Maybe you can work out how to undo raising to the third power.

Comment: Thank u so much. J^3 will be the answer?

Comment: Likely not -- I'm just pointing you toward something to explore, and if you pay attention to your calculation you should be able to figure out how to solve the problem.  (Importantly, you should be able to verify your answer.  In the end, make sure to check that $A^3$ is that matrix, and if it isn't you didn't get the answer.)

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{bmatrix} 64 && 64 \\ -9 && 16 \end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{(64)(25)} \begin{bmatrix} 16 && -64 \\ 9 && 64 \end{bmatrix}$

Diagonalize this last matrix, eigenvalues are the roots of

$ (\lambda - 16) (\lambda - 64) + 64(9) = 0 $

which is

$ \lambda^2 - 80 \lambda + 64(25) = 0 $

The roots (the eigenvalues) are

$\lambda_{1, 2} = \frac{1}{2} (80 \pm \sqrt{6400 - 6400} ) = 40, 40 $

Next find the eigenvectors corresponding to this repeated eigenvalue:

Let $v = [x, y]^T $ then

$\begin{bmatrix} 24 && 64 \\ -9 && -24 \end{bmatrix} $

Hence $v_1 = [8, -3] $

Next, find a specific generalized eigenvector by solving the system

$\begin{bmatrix} -24&&-64\\9&&24\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = c \begin{bmatrix} 8 \\ - 3 \end{bmatrix} $

where $\large c = 3 (40)^{\frac{2}{3}}$

The above linear system implies, $ -24 x - 64 y = 8c $ whose solution is

$ v_2 = [-c/3 , 0] + [-8/3, 1] = [-(c + 8) / 3, 1] $

Let the matrix of eigenvectors be

$P = [v_1, v_2] = \begin{bmatrix} 8 && -(c+8)/3 \\ -3 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Then we can write,

$\begin{bmatrix} 16 && -64 \\ 9 && 64 \end{bmatrix} = P J_1 P^{-1} $

where $J_1$ is matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 40 && c \\ 0 && 40 \end{bmatrix} $

So now we can write

$(64)(25) A^3 = P J_1 P^{-1} $

Thus by taking the cubic root, we can write,

$ \sqrt[3]{64(25)} A = P \sqrt[3]{J_1} P^{-1} $

It is easy to see that

$\sqrt[3]{J_1 } = \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt[3]{40} && 1 \\ 0 && \sqrt[3] {40} \end{bmatrix} $

Hence, matrix $A$ is

$A = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1600}} \begin{bmatrix} 8 && -(c+8)/3 \\ -3 && 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt[3]{40} && 1 \\ 0 &&\sqrt[3] {40} \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} 8 && -(c+8)/3 \\ -3 && 1 \end{bmatrix}^{-1}$

Comment: Hi thank you so much but eigen values are 1/40 or 40?

Answer (score 0):

Start with $A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Then

$A^3=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a \left(a^2+b c\right)+c (a b+b d) & b \left(a^2+b c\right)+d (a b+b d) \\
 a (a c+c d)+c \left(b c+d^2\right) & b (a c+c d)+d \left(b c+d^2\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Also $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 64 & 64 \\
 -9 & 16 \\
\end{array}
\right)^{-1}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{100} & -\frac{1}{25} \\
 \frac{9}{1600} & \frac{1}{25} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

So, all you need to do is solve

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a \left(a^2+b c\right)+c (a b+b d) & b \left(a^2+b c\right)+d (a b+b d) \\
 a (a c+c d)+c \left(b c+d^2\right) & b (a c+c d)+d \left(b c+d^2\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{100} & -\frac{1}{25} \\
 \frac{9}{1600} & \frac{1}{25} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

One possible solution is

$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{5} (-2) \sqrt[3]{-\frac{1}{5}} & \frac{4}{15} \sqrt[3]{-\frac{1}{5}} \\
 \frac{1}{80} (-3) \sqrt[3]{-\frac{1}{5}} & \frac{1}{5} (-3) \sqrt[3]{-\frac{1}{5}} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

There are other solutions, you can find.

Answer (score 0):

We want to solve $A^3 = B^{-1}$, where $B$ is the matrix in the question.
Basically we want to compute $B^{-{1 \over 3}}$.

With
$V=\begin{bmatrix} 584 & 3 \\ -219 & 8 \end{bmatrix}$, we have $V^{-1} B V= J_{40}$, where $J_\lambda$ is a Jordan block with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Note that $J_{40} = 40 (I + N)$, where $N= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & {1 \over 40} \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, and $N^2 = 0$. The binomial theorem gives
$(I+N)^{-{1 \over 3}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-{1 \over 3}}{k} N^k = I -{1 \over 3}N$, from which we have $J_{40}^{-{1 \over 3}} = 40^{-{1 \over 3}} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -{1 \over 120} \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and so
$A = V J_{40}^{-{1 \over 3}} V^{-1}$ is a solution.

More generally, we can choose a branch of $f(z) = z^{-{1 \over 3}}$ and use the formula in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2659732/27978.

Comment: Hi thank you so much but eigen values are 1/40 or 40?

Comment: I found the eigenvalues for the integer matrix, and the constant $1600$ I moved to the left hand side as you notice at the end.

Comment: Then how did you find 584 -219 :S

Comment: @David The eigenvalues of $B$ are both $40$. First I found $v_1=(8,-3)^T$ to be an eigenvector of $B$ and the I solved $(B-40I) v_2=v_1$. To get a 'nice' answer (integers) I had to multiply the $v_2$ I found by $73$ which is where the $(584,-219)^T$ came from. No need to this of course, but it looks nicer :-).